# mtp:udi=/org/kde/solid/udev/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4 does not exist error

Tags: kde, dolphin, mtp, samsung, konqueror

Trying to connect to a Samsung Galaxy phone in MTP mode, Konquerer or Dolphin in KDE 4.14.3 throws the following error:

```
mtp:udi=/org/kde/solid/udev/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4
```

Why?

Comment: [Please don't multipost](http://superuser.com/questions/857586/mtpudi-org-kde-solid-udev-sys-devices-pci000000-0000001d-0-usb2-2-1-2-1-4-e)

Comment: @JanDvorak: I've deleted [the thread on Superuser](http://superuser.com/q/857586/261550).